# how to disable left and right arrow in slide using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a slide when the image is first the left arrow should be hide and when the last image is active right arrow should be hide.  I had added my code here. Is there any other alternative method to replace or any new method. Is there any option to modify the code, Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
$("[id^=viewDocs]").on("click", function () {
  var docId = $(this).attr("id");
  var docIndex = docId.substr(docId.length - 1);
  var activeItemId = $(this).data("value");                                           
  $("div>div.item").removeClass("active");
  $("#"+activeItemId).addClass("active"); 
  var appName = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_appName').val();
  var paramValue = $(this).data("id");
  $("#myModal").removeClass("hidden");
  $('#downloadDocId').attr('href',appName+'/apps/PatientDetailsDoctor/ViewPatientTestResults/downloadUploadDocs?testResultsDocsId='+paramValue);
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");                                                                             
  modal.style.display = "block";                          
});                                 

$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
  var itemId = ev.relatedTarget.id;
  var paramValue =  $('#'+itemId).data('value');
  var appName = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_appName').val();
  $('#downloadDocId').attr('href',appName+'/apps/PatientDetailsDoctor/ViewPatientTestResults/downloadUploadDocs?testResultsDocsId='+paramValue);
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > div,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="downloadDocId" href="/doctorclinic/apps/PatientDetailsDoctor/ViewPatientTestResults/downloadUploadDocs?testResultsDocsId=100250">
  <span class="download-file" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i></span>
</a>
<a id="downloadDocId" href="#"> 
  <span class="close-popup" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">×</span>        
</a>    
<div class="modal-content1" id="img01">           
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li id="indicator1" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li id="indicator2" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li id="insesrtIndicator" class="hidden"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div id="insertCarouselItem" class="hidden"></div> 
      <div class="item active" data-value="100250" id="docPdf1">
        <div id="pdfDoc1">
          <canvas height="841" width="595" style="display: block;"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item" data-value="100301" id="docImage2"></div>
    </div>          
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="display: none;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these JavaScript codes.

**First:**

```
$('.left').hide();

$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
  var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
  var currentIndex = carouselData.getActiveIndex();

  if (currentIndex >= 1) {
    $('.left').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.left').hide();
  }

  if (currentIndex === (carouselData.$items.length-1)) {
    $('.right').hide();
    $('.left').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.right').show();
  }
})
```

**Second**

```
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slid', '', checkitem);

$(document).ready(function(){
    checkitem();
});

function checkitem()
{
  var $this = $('#myCarousel');
  if($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')) {
    $this.children('.left.carousel-control').hide();
  } else if($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')) {
    $this.children('.right.carousel-control').hide();
  } else {
    $this.children('.carousel-control').show();
  } 
}
```

Here I used the second JavaScript example and made what you want:

```js
$('.left').hide();

$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
  var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
  var currentIndex = carouselData.getActiveIndex();

  if (currentIndex >= 1) {
    $('.left').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.left').hide();
  }

  if (currentIndex === (carouselData.$items.length-1)) {
    $('.right').hide();
    $('.left').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.right').show();
  }
})
```

```html
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
      
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="//placehold.it/1024x600" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              one
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="//placehold.it/1024x600/999" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              two
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="//placehold.it/1024x600/bbb" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              three
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      
      </div>  
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it'll helps you. Good luck! :)

Comment: when the image is first left arrow disabled, but when the image is at last still left arrow disabled and right arrow present.

Comment: So sorry I don't undertood. You said: "when the image is first the left arrow should be hide and when the last image is active right arrow should be hide." Right?

Comment: correct, your code works correct when the image is first.  when the image is at last right arrow should hide,but the arrow is still there.

Comment: But when the third, the last image showed the right arrow hide, then when the first image started again the right arrow showed again like how you wanted.